# vim navigation - last character which is not a semi-colon or comma

Tags: vim, navigation

I work with PHP and Javascript a lot and I find that I am often adding an open parenthesis `(` in the middle of a line somewhere (calling a function or something) and then I need to move to the end of the line to close it...

example (before edits):

```
array(
  'key' => 'value sometimes long and with \',() in string',
```

example (after initial edit - exit insert mode on the close paren `)`):

```
array(
  'key' => Class::method('value sometimes long and with \',() in string',
                        ^ cursor here after exiting insert mode
```

desired cursor position in insert mode:

```
array(
  'key' => Class::method('value sometimes long and with \',() in string',
                                     cursor before comma in insert mode ^
```

obviously, I could do `$hi` to move to the end of the line, move back one character and enter insert mode... or I could do `A<` to enter insert mode at the EOL and left arrow one place.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any easier/better way to do this?

Better yet, I am imagining a simple function to "know" if the last character is a comma or semicolon, and move to the last character and only move left if the last character is a comma or semicolon.

pseudo code idea: `$("am I on a comma or semicolon" ? h : )i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do `iClass::method<Esc>lva'S)` with the excellent [Surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/) plugin by Tim Pope.

Comment: You beat me to it! surround.vim was made for exactly this type of situation.

Answer (score 2):

The only standard key sequence I can think of is using <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> to do a one-off normal command. E.g. <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> would get you into the right position. If you have `imap <C-b> <Left>` you can do this without leaving the home row.

Comment: Some people also like to use emacs/shell-like mappings for this, eg. `:inoremap <C-E> <End>`.

Answer (score 2):

I got used to automatic character pairing in my TextMate days. There are a bunch of plugins offering that functionality in Vim; I use DelimitMate.

The idea is to automatically close `()[]{}''""` pairs when you type the first character. That way, you never have to do the gymnastic you are talking about.